# Confused about the TinyMCE image plugin documentation as far as drag-and-drop, etc

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-6

I'm looking at the Tiny documentation for the image plugin here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/image/

For example, it says

```
"This is not drag-drop functionality and the user is required to enter the path to the image."
```

Currently I'm using Tiny v5 and was thinking about upgrading to v6. With the image plugin enabled *or disabled* I can drag and drop an image to upload it into the editor, and get it automatically resized to fit nicely and save space.

And even with the plugin disabled I can touch the image and drag the corners to resize it.

Is this basic functionality changed in the way images are uploaded in v6? I'm trying to decide whether to upgrade to v6 or not.

Thanks.